# Zero-inflated two-part models for semi-continuous data

Tags: data-transformation, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, zero-inflation

I am trying to study predictors of companies' pollution output of some specific chemicals. The data I am using have many 0's (i.e., the company did not pollute at all with those chemicals) and then are continuous with a long right tail. I have seen others model this data by logging the dependent variable after adding 1. My sense is that this is wrong, but I don't understand why. Could someone explain? This approach is much simpler than what I think I should be doing - using zero-inflated two-part models for semi-continuous data - so I'd be thrilled if it turned out simply adding 1 and logging is right.

Second, I have found a Stata ado file to run zero-inflated two-part models for semi-continuous data. Is there a way to incorporate fixed effects into this type of model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Stata, but R can run zero-inflated models with fixed effects. Check out, for example, the `gamlss` package and `zeroinfl()` from the `pscl` package.

Answer (score 4):

1. Disadvantages of $\ln(0+c)$:

   - $c=1$ is arbitrary. Often the value of $c$ changes estimates, so you need to conduct a grid search for the "optimal" result and justify
     that choice in the end
   - Zero mass may respond differently to covariates (extensive vs. intensive margin may have different DGPs)
   - Retransformation back to natural scale problem is worse at the low end if you want to predict $y$
   - Sometimes works poorly. See Duan, N., W.G. Manning, et al. “A Comparison of Alternative Models for the Demand for Medical Care,”
     *Journal of Business and Economics Statistics*, 1:115-126, 1983 for some examples. ([gated JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1391852), [RAND working paper link](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reports/2006/R2754.pdf)).
2. There's no panel version of `tpm`. I would try using dummies and
   clustering on the panel id if computationally possible. I might also
   give `xtpoisson, fe robust` or `xtpqml` (a user-written wrapper) a whirl, justifying it as Quasi-MLE, which has [performed well in CS simulations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176511001741) even when the number of zeros is large.

Comment: [`xtnbreg`](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?xtnbreg) is good to note as well. I've estimated good fitting models with up to 65% zero observations using the negative binomial.