# Does there exist zero-inflated linear regression?

Tags: regression, zero-inflation

I have a non-count data with huge number of zeros in the target variable. I need to fit a model being a mixture of Dirac delta function and normal distribution parametrized by mean $X\beta$ and variance $\sigma^2$, with mixing proportion $\pi$, i.e.

$$ y \sim \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 0 & \text{ with probability }\pi 
\\
\mathcal{N}\left(X \beta, \sigma^2 \right) & \text{ with probability } 1-\pi\end{array} \right.$$

to account for the excess zeros. Could you provide me with any references about such models? Or maybe there is some approach that is better, then the above, for continuous, zero-inflated data?

Comment: If you have a genuine expectation that the true distribution is indeed a zero-inflated normal, then just fit that model and be done with it.  Whether other approaches are better depends on whether the expectation/evidence that some other choice of distribution is a better approximation to nature.

Edited to add: it seems an odd sampling process that both deals with continuous data and has a huge number of integers (zeros) in it.

Comment: @user43849 the process that produces such data is very easy to imagine: think of some kind of device that is idle for most of the time, but sometimes fires some continuous signals.

Comment: Interestingly, the Wiki excerpt of the [tag:zero-inflation] tag says *there is zero-inflated normal regression*. Not that this would help, but I find it curious.

Comment: @RichardHardy I wasn't able to find *any* references dealing with such models, this is how the question emerged...

Comment: When it's non-zero is the response positive?

Comment: @Glen_b unfortunately not, otherwise this would be a Tobit model.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no covariates that are associated w/ $\pi$?

Comment: @gung here asking just about the simplest case.

Comment: In Epidemiology, this is a common problem and the term for such variables is "spike at zero". However, all methods that I am aware of are assuming non-negative values. But maybe the term helps to find extensions to negative values.

Answer (score 2):

I have found 2 references so far using *zero-inflated normal regression*, one in medical research and the other in animal conservation:

- [Semiparametric zero-inflated modeling in multi-ethnic study of atherosclerosis (mesa)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3690929/#S2title): note that they use $\log(y+1)$-transform: $f(y) = \log(y+1)$ , so it could be problematic (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87338) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52285/how-to-interpret-a-log-transformed-x1#comment102184_52306)).
- [A drop in immigration results in the extinction of a local woodchat shrike population](https://zslpublications.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/acv.12639?casa_token=643G7mDjY1sAAAAA%3Au7gUAS7bzTg4k5FKct68FsVREGJl4XrViNkLXAg-voEaG65NM7LuemvoJbaqTq-sXk5CzzVoaUiu): it looks like Bayesian models.

Both the response variables, *Agatston scores of CAC* and *[the number of fledglings of brood](https://zslpublications.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1111%2Facv.12639&file=acv12639-sup-0001-Supinfo.pdf)*, are probably non-negative, however.